# Why model in tensor flow model zoo have low mAP?

Tags: tensorflow

I read in paper and article SSD model achieved above 70% mAP but when i browse through tensor flow model zoo, the mAP of SSD is around 30-40% in this link
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md Why is it much lower to the mAP in paper?

Comment: One potential reason why the mAP in the tensor flow model zoo is much lower than the mAP in the paper could be that the data used to train the model was not of high quality. Additionally, it is possible that the model was not trained for long enough or that the model was not configured correctly and thus did not perform as well as it could have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check whether the 0.70 mAP reported for SSD is for the CoCo dataset. I'm guessing it is for a much easier dataset like VOC2007 as reported in the original paper.

As far as I know, none of the current SOTA detection models have been able to achieve 0.70 mAP on coco. See:

https://paperswithcode.com/sota/object-detection-on-coco

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is from pascal VOC dataset, I wrongly saw the data.